# Chart of blood pH across different animal species?

Tags: zoology, hematology, ph

How does blood pH vary across species?  I can't find an article or chart listing this kind of information.

So far I've found bits and pieces like:

- [Human blood pH is nominally 7.4.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1114160/#__p11)
- [7.4 seems to be a good value for dogs and cats](http://www.2ndchance.info/normaldogandcatbloodvalues.htm) (¿and probably all mammals?).
- [For racehorses it seems to be roughly 7.4.](http://www.phmiracleliving.com/Articles/2006-12-29-pHofAnimalBlood.html)
- [Silkworm, *Bombyx Mori*, blood (hemolymph) has a pH of 6.45 (larval) and 6.57 (pupal).](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2147577/)
- Bullfrog *muscle*(!) pH runs roughly 7 to 7.3.  <sup>([Link to *The Journal of Experimental Biology* article, PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjC84r5hr_LAhVO32MKHQJ5DpsQFggsMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjeb.biologists.org%2Fcontent%2Fjexbio%2F203%2F13%2F2065.full.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGkQCOzdsgJrTcCu5Amfq5WBVSgXQ))</sup> It's not clear if this is also blood pH.

But no real comparison.

**Is there an authoritative comparison of blood pH between: mammals, reptiles, fish, invertebrates, etc.?**

Is nominal/average pH at least constant across all mammals, or across all reptiles, etc.?

Comment: Don't forget most plant life needs soil that has a pH of 6.0 to 7.4 to dissolve nutrients easily, so you might as well add plant life to your list

Comment: @TheVoid, Sure, any plants that have blood. (^_^)

Comment: Its all life that needs a pH of level of 7.4 to be in the Alkaline. That is wear life can thrive at its fullest potential.

Comment: in reptiles variation from 6.5 to 8.1 have been observed. ectotherms in general have a broader range. http://jeb.biologists.org/content/jexbio/203/13/2065.full.pdf

Comment: @John, that's the exact same reference I used and I don't see anywhere where it says blood pH was in those ranges.  What paragraph or table are you looking at?

Comment: oh sorry that was the reference for the ectoderm statement. here s the reference for the PH values. http://www.seaturtle.org/pdf/dessauerhc_1970_inbiologyofthereptilia_p1-72.pdf

Comment: @John, Thanks!  Just skimmed it so far, but it seems to show that *baseline* is about 7.4-ish but it lowers dramatically during dives or other activities where CO2 builds up.  That would be extreme (in the) ocean acidification. :)

Comment: Crocodiles can do some weird things with their blood and even have different ph values for different parts of the body, http://compphys.bio.uci.edu/BENNETT/pubs/65.pdf but crocodile circulation is weird to begin with.

Comment: for non-crodilian reptiles there is also a strong relation ship between body temprature and PH, this alone could account for why birds and mammals are so stable.

Comment: insects have some wide ranges too. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2140737/

Comment: birds average 7.5 -7.6 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0300962982902006?via%3Dihub