# What is blood pH for different animals?

Tags: zoology, physiology, hematology, red-blood-cell, ph

So we all know that humans average blood pH is 7.4. But is it the same for the animals?
I need examples of animals with the same blood pH as humans and the ones with different blood pH.
I guess dogs and cats have almost the same pH am I right?

Comment: This question has been asked before -- [Chart of blood pH across different animal species?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44268).  However, since there is no answer to the original question, yours is not technically a duplicate.  I recommend looking at the comments on the older question, as they link to some resources for blood pH of reptiles, insects, and birds.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which species or groups you are interested in. Can you be more specific than "the animals"? Note that many animals don't even have blood! e.g. insects and hemolymph. For example, sharks have relatively acidic blood: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-Mean-SEM-blood-pH-levels-in-the-Atlantic-sharpnose-shark-during-a-60-min-stress_fig2_226732907, https://academic.oup.com/conphys/article/5/1/cox012/3055083. But I don't know if that is something that you are interested in.

Comment: I'm interested mainly in carnivores v/s herbivorous. The alkaline diet claim that as we humans have a slightly basic pH we shouldn't eat acidic food like meat. It would be a nice counter-example if carnivores have a similar pH as herbivores.

Comment: @heracho a little confused as you are different from user Jane who posted the question. But it would be helpful to have this directly in the question rather than in comments discussion.

Comment: I don't think I should edit the question to my particular interest. Although I believed that my question (Is there any correlation between species diet and blood pH?) is too close to this one as to be a new one.

Comment: *The alkaline diet claim that as we humans have a slightly basic pH we shouldn't eat acidic food like meat. It would be a nice counter-example if carnivores have a similar pH as herbivores.* -- I think a question concerning animal diet and blood pH is more interesting and easier to answer than the very general question posted above.  This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/722486).

Comment: Good point @acvill, I'm going to post this specific question.